# Mixing units in calc in media queries in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, css-calc

I am currently trying to use `calc()` with mixed units (`ch` and `rem` in my case) in a CSS media query. It seems to be working across browsers, except for Chrome.

Here's my statement:

```
@media screen and (min-width: calc(40ch * 2 + 15ch + 8rem)) {}
```

While other browsers calculate this correctly:

```
@media screen and (min-width: calc(95ch + 8rem)) {}
```

…Chrome would interpret the above statement as:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 103px) {}
```

(It appears that Chrome ignores all units and assumes `px` )

Is there a comparable workaround, or is this a Chrome thing?

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=915190